# Custom route constraint doesn't work for root route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My constraint works but it only works if there is a path in my URL:

```
www.example.com/hello/world
```

It will not work for the root path like:

```
www.example.com
```

**How can I get my route to work for the root domain also?**

```
get '*path', to: 'account#index', 
        constraints: AccountConstraint.new
```

Comment: Have you tried `root to: 'account#index', constraints: AccountConstraint.new`?